# Display information received over network in a Java JFrame

Tags: java, swing, class, user-interface

I'm writing a program in Java to allow users to view what DIS (Distributed Interactive Simulation) is being sent/ received over a network. I currently have the program set up so that it reads the information, and displays it in the console- it does this for as long as it is running (i.e. until I click 'Stop').

I am now trying to create a GUI to display this information to the user. I have a `Gui.java` class, and I also have an `EspduReceiver.java` class, which is where I am reading the DIS information that is being sent across the network, and displaying it in the console.

I now want to display the DIS information that I am reading into my program to the user via the Gui class.

My Gui class currently looks like this:

```
package openDIS;

import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class Gui extends JFrame{

public Gui(){
    setTitle("DIS Filter");
    setSize(1000, 500);
    setLocation (10, 10);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    initGui();
}

/*public quitButton(){
    initGui();
} */

private void initGui(){
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();

    frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setTitle("DIS Filter");
    frame.setSize(1000, 500);

    panel.setLayout(null);

    /*Create a String to hold the PDU information to be displayed in the JTextArea */
    String output = EspduReceiver.pdu;

    /*Add a JTextArea to display the output DIS information */
    //JTextArea output = new JTextArea();
    panel.add(new JTextArea(output));

    JButton quitButton = new JButton("Quit");
    quitButton.setBounds(875, 400, 80, 30); /*Set the location of the button in the window, and its size */

    quitButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });


    panel.add(quitButton);
    setTitle("Quit");
    //setSize(60,30); /*This line was overwriting the previously set values for the size of the window */
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);        
}

public static void main(String[] args){ /* I probably don't need a main method here- I have one in EspduReceiver.java */
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run(){
            Gui gui = new Gui();
            gui.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}




}
```

and my EspduReceiver class currently looks like this:

```
package openDIS;

import java.net.*;
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;

import edu.nps.moves.disutil.*;
import edu.nps.moves.dis.*;

/*Receives PDUs from the network in IEEE format. */

public class EspduReceiver {

/*Max size of a PDU in binary format that we can receive. Outdated- PDUs can be larger- but this is a reasonable starting point */
public static final int MAX_PDU_SIZE = 8192;

public static void main(String args[]){

    MulticastSocket socket;
    DatagramPacket packet;
    InetAddress address;
    PduFactory pduFactory = new PduFactory();

    try{
        /*Specify the socket to receive the data */
        socket = new MulticastSocket(EspduSender.PORT);
        address = InetAddress.getByName(EspduSender.DEFAULT_MULTICAST_GROUP);
        socket.joinGroup(address); 

        /*Loop infinitely, receiving datagrams */
        while(true){
            byte buffer[] = new byte[MAX_PDU_SIZE];
            packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);

            socket.receive(packet);

            Pdu pdu = pduFactory.createPdu(packet.getData());

            if(pdu != null){
                System.out.print("Got PDU of type: " + pdu.getClass().getName());
                if(pdu instanceof EntityStatePdu){
                    EntityID eid = ((EntityStatePdu)pdu).getEntityID();
                    Vector3Double position = ((EntityStatePdu)pdu).getEntityLocation();
                    System.out.print(" EID:[" + eid.getSite() + ", " + eid.getApplication() + ", " + eid.getEntity() + "] ");
                    System.out.print(" Location in DIS coordinates: [" + position.getX() + ", " + position.getY() + ", " + position.getZ() + "]");
                } else if(!(pdu instanceof EntityStatePdu)){
                    System.out.println("There are no PDUs currently being received.");
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
        } /*end while */
    } /*end try */
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("This is where the error is being generated");
        /*09/04/2014 @ 17:100
         * If this exception gets called, presumably it either means that pdu is not an instance of EntityStatePdu, or
         * that pdu does not actually hold a packet.  */
    }
} /*end main */

} /*end class */
```

Currently, when I try to run my Gui.java class, I get an error with the line `String output = EspduReceiver.pdu;` - it says:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: pdu cannot be resolved or is not a field"

I am wondering if this is because my `pdu` variable is created inside a `try- catch` method in my EspduReceiver.java class- and so is not visible to anything outside that block of code? I have tried declaring it as a global variable in the EspduReceiver.java class instead, but that caused several new errors...

Can anyone advise me how I can set the value of my `output` String in my Gui.java class to the value of my `pdu` variable in my EspduReceiver.java class? Or should I be using another data type rather than a String to hold it? Basically, how can I present the data from the `pdu` variable on screen via the use of my Gui.java class?

Thanks!

**Edit 15/04/2014**

Hey, thanks for your answer- I've tried what you suggested, but I am getting an error on the line `pdu = pduFactory.createPdu(packet.getData());` which says: "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field pdu." I changed `public Pdu pdu;` to `public static Pdu pdu;`, and that has got rid of that error, but now nothing happens when I try to run my EspduReceiver.java class.

My Gui.java class now compiles, but when I try to run it, the console displays a message that says: "Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException". It's complaining about the following lines:

```
initGui();

String output = EspduReceiver.pdu.toString();

Gui gui = new Gui();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are typing `EspduReceiver.pdu`, that means, you want to get a value of `pdu` field of `EspduReceiver` class. But this class has no such field. So, just add it:

```
public class EspduReceiver {
    public static final int MAX_PDU_SIZE = 8192;
    public static Pdu pdu;
    ...
}
```

And replace this:

```
 Pdu pdu = pduFactory.createPdu(packet.getData());
```

With this:

```
 pdu = pduFactory.createPdu(packet.getData());
```

But later, at the GUI class, you should get `String` content of `pdu`. I've never faced with this class, but if it's a class described [here](http://www.snmp4j.org/doc/org/snmp4j/PDU.html), I think you can get the data in the following way:

```
String output = EspduReceiver.pdu.toString();
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer- I've tried making the changes you suggested, but I'm still getting some problems- I've amended my original question to show the changes made and the errors I'm now getting.

Comment: @someone2088 my typo, edited my answer, you should make it `static`

Comment: nikis- I tried this- as I mentioned in the edit to my original post. This got rid of the error, but now nothing happens when I try to run my EspduReceiver.java class, and I'm getting another error in my Gui.java class...

Comment: @someone2088 you should check the value of `pdu` after `createPdu` execution

Comment: I assume you mean check the value by printing it in the console? I can't do this, because my class no longer runs- as mentioned in my Edit. I don't get any output at all when trying to run the EspduReceiver.java class... When trying to run the Gui.java class, I get the NullPointerException that I mentioned... any suggestions for how to resolve these issues?

Comment: @someone2088 looking on the info you've posted, it's clear, that EspduReceiver.pdu is `null` after the execution of `pdu = pduFactory.createPdu(packet.getData());`, so you should find why it's `null`

Comment: EspduReceiver.pdu wasn't null before I made any changes to my code- I could run my EspduReceiver.java class, and would receive output in the console that would say "Got PDU of type: " and specify some information about the PDU- I knew that it was picking up the correct information, as I was able to see the same PDUs being transferred across the network using a program called DISLink monitor... I've just tried changing the code back to how it was originally (as it is in my question), run it, and the console will continuously print statements such as:

Comment: `Got PDU of type: edu.nps.moves.dis.EntityStatePdu EID:[1, 104, 376] Location in DIS coordinates: [4000210.56211154, -148959.78046740193, 4949155.827042254]`, so clearly EspduReceiver.pdu is storing the information about each PDU as it is transferred across the network- because I get hundreds of these statements in the console- more keep appearing as long as the program is running, i.e. it is picking up every PDU that's being sent over the network for as long as it is running.